# Не работает код SQLiteOpenHelper на kotlin

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

У меня есть рабочая версия кода на Java, и мне бы хотелось переписать код на kotlin, но в конце у меня возникала проблема с методом query, он видимо ругается на неправильную реализацию, но я не знаю как это исправить. Смотрите изображение.

```
class LocalBDLessonsInternetKt(var  mContext : Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(mContext, DB_PATH, null, 2){

    var myDataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    companion object {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        var mContext : Context  = LocalBDLessonsInternetKt.mContext
        var DB_PATH : String = "/data/data/${mContext.packageName}/databases/"
    }


    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createDataBase() {
        val dbExist = checkDataBase()
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.readableDatabase
            try {
                copyDataBase()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                throw Error("Error copying database")
            }

        }
    }

    private fun checkDataBase(): Boolean {
        try {
            val myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
        }

        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase!!.close()
        }
        return if (myDataBase != null) true else false
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copyDataBase() {
        val myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME)
        val outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
        val myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)
        val buffer = ByteArray(10)
        var length: Int = 0
        while ({length = myInput!!.read(buffer); length} () != 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }
        myOutput.flush()
        myOutput.close()
        myInput.close()

    }

    @Throws(SQLException::class)
    fun openDataBase() {
        val myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)

    }

    @Synchronized override fun close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase!!.close()
        super.close()
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()

            }

    }


    fun setQuery(table: String,
                 columns: Array<String>,
                 selection: String,
                 selectionArgs: Array<String>,
                 groupBy: String,
                 having: String,
                 sortOrder: String): Cursor {

        return myDataBase.query(table = table,
                columns = columns,
                selection = selection,
                selectionArgs = selectionArgs,
                groupBy = groupBy,
                having = having,
                sortOrder = sortOrder)

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

```
Error:(111, 28) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun query(p0: Boolean, p1: String!, p2: Array<(out) String!>!, p3: String!, p4: Array<(out) String!>!, p5: String!, p6: String!, p7: String!, p8: String!): Cursor! defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
public open fun query(p0: Boolean, p1: String!, p2: Array<(out) String!>!, p3: String!, p4: Array<(out) String!>!, p5: String!, p6: String!, p7: String!, p8: String!, p9: CancellationSignal!): Cursor! defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
public open fun query(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) String!>!, p2: String!, p3: Array<(out) String!>!, p4: String!, p5: String!, p6: String!): Cursor! defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
public open fun query(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) String!>!, p2: String!, p3: Array<(out) String!>!, p4: String!, p5: String!, p6: String!, p7: String!): Cursor! defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
```

Comment: зачем эти `=`? пишите не `table = table`, а просто `table`,так же и все другие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в имени параметра, должно быть:

```
return myDataBase.query(table = table,
            columns = columns,
            selection = selection,
            selectionArgs = selectionArgs,
            groupBy = groupBy,
            having = having,
            orderBy = sortOrder)
```

И да, не пишите вы их, меньше путаться будете :)

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли.